# Passport Get user by Access token Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, laravel-passport

Need to built an api system for laravel using passport.In larvel5.2 Oauth 2 Integration there is a seperate class Authorizer to perform the action way to get the user data by access token

```
      Authorizer::getResourceOwnerId();
```

But in passport there is no seperate methood to get User details based on the access token.Anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After user authentication, you can use the `Auth:user()` to retrieve the user information

Comment: What if i am not using Auth package in laravel. Moreover i am using it to create Api